# Using a variable without causing circular dependancy

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, include

I have 5 sets of ".h" & ".cpp" files:

- Main.cpp
- Game.h, Game.cpp
- Parent.h, Parent.cpp
- Child1.h, Child1.cpp
- Child2.h, Child2.cpp

Main does not contain a class, nor does it contain a header file - and is the starting point for the application. Among other things, it initializes the variable "myGame" of type "Game" using information collected.

**Main.cpp**

```
#include "Game.h"
...
Game myGame(*parameters sent to constructor*)
```

Game is the body of my application. It's header includes Child1 and Child2 and initializes variables with those types. It declares the class "Game"

**Game.h**

```
#pragma once

#include "Child1.h"
#include "Child2.h"

class Game
{
public:
    Game(HWND hWnd, ...);
    ~Game();

    Child1 child1Obj;
    Child2 child2obj[20];
    ...
private:
    ...
};
```

Parent generalizes the two child classes, and provides like functions and variables. It's header does not include other files.

**Parent.h**

```
#pragma once

class Parent
{
public:
    Parent(void);
    ~Parent(void);
    ...
};
```

Child1 and Child2 are both similar, and include the parent header.

**Child1.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "Parent.h"

class Child1 :
    public Parent
{
public:
    Child1();
    ~Child1();
};
```

I want to be able to use the data contained in `Game` in `Parent`, `Child1` and `Child2`.

My first guess was to simply insert `#include "Game.h"` to the top of `Parent.h`, but doing so would cause circular dependencies.

Next, I thought that I'd just have to reference the actual game object `myGame.` (created in `Main.cpp`) whenever I wanted to use variables and functions in `Game`. But I wasn't sure how to do this. Perhaps I could declare `myGame` within a `Main.h` file in advance like the following:

**Main.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "Game.h"

Game myGame;
```

But in order to do that I'd still have to use `#include "Game.h"`, and include "Main.h" at the top of files that I want to use `myGame` in - leading to the same circular dependency problem as described above.

Is there any way I can:

1. Declare an uninitialized `myGame` of type Game in "Main.h"
2. Initialize `myGame` with the information collected in "Main.cpp"
3. Use `myGame` in Parent, Child1 and Child2 without causing circular dependency by including the file that `myGame` is declared in.

Am I able to use `#include "Game.h"` within "Main.h" to create a Game variable, but prevent include inheritance to files that include "Main.h"?

Comment: How do Parent, Child1, and Child2 need to use Game? Maybe you can use forward decls for Game.

Comment: MacklinB, of course this type of issue occurs in both [C] and [C++].  However, the question code is obviously not [C].  Perhaps you should consider editing your question, and removing the [C] tag?

Comment: Do `#include "Game.h"` in `Parent.cpp` . The `Parent` class definition cannot rely on `Game`, although it can accepts pointers or references via a forward declaration.  Of course, function bodies in `Parent.cpp` can use full `Game`s.

Answer (score 2):

**forward declaration** allows referencing objects that haven't been defined, but they can't be instantiated without a definition.  It says "I'll tell you about it later".

Illegal:

```
class myGame;  // forward declaration, I'll tell you about this later
class myPlayer
{
public:
  myPlayer();
protected:
  myGame theGame;
}
```

Legal:

```
class myGame;  // forward declaration, I'll tell you about this later
class myPlayer
{
public:
  myPlayer();
protected:
  myGame* theGame;
}
```

The "later", which you promised the compiler in the header file, is the source file.

myPlayer.cpp:

```
#inlcude "myPlayer.h"

// Tell the compiler what a myGame is, 
// other than something that can be pointed at
#inlcude "myGame.h" 

myPlayer::myPlayer() :
  theGame(new myGame())
{
}
```

Naturally, a real program will be substantially more complicated, with parameters to constructors, etc.  This demonstration is about the structure of the classes, the files describing them and their interlocking relationships.

The drawback of a forward declaration is that the compiler gets no information about the object being forward declared, so it can't make one - and as such, it can't put one inside another object.  Having said that, you can point off to one, because you've said there is such a thing as the-thing-you-have-forward-declared and as such it's legal to do things with those things, like take their memory address and thus point at them, or have a reference to one.

By the time the compiler gets deeper into the source file, the .cpp, you've handed over definitions for the forward declared objects and now it knows what they are and what can be done with them.  That's the point where you can do things with the pointer or reference, like make a `new` one, or call functions on it.

Comment: This solves my 200+ errors when I have `#include "Game.h"` in `Parent.h`, but causes errors when I try to use any type under my `Parent` class. Child1 and Child2 are also erroring out at my class declaration "'Parent' : base class undefined".

Comment: Your edit doesn't work for me, because when creating an instance of myGame in myPlayer.cpp, I need to pass 3 parameters that aren't available in myPlayer - but in Main.

Comment: @MaklinB, you didn't mention anything about that in your question.  Perhaps you'd like to ask a new question?